# React Route v6 calling import in element

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

As we are using React v6 how can use this functionality in Route with element can be used
we are using typescript

I am able to run the same with v5 with components

```
<Route path="/" element={() => import('user/App')} />
```

'()  => Promise' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode' for react route element

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`lazy`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/lazy) prop to lazily import the route component.

> Each lazy function will typically return the result of a dynamic
> import.
>
> ```
> let routes = createRoutesFromElements(
>   <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
>     <Route path="a" lazy={() => import("./a")} />
>     <Route path="b" lazy={() => import("./b")} />
>   </Route>
> );
> ```

```
<Route path="/" lazy={() => import('user/App')} />
```

This feature only works if you are using a Data router. If you want to dynamically import the routed components with one of non-data routers you'll need to follow the older [lazy-loading](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/tree/dev/examples/lazy-loading) example.

Example:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

const App = React.lazy(() => import("user/App"));

...

<Routes>
  <Route
    path="/"
    element={
      <React.Suspense fallback={<>...</>}>
        <App />
      </React.Suspense>
    }
  />
</Routes>
```

Comment: I am using browserrouter

Comment: @SpringLearner If it's a browser router using [createBrowserRouter](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-browser-router) you can use the Data APIs, otherwise if it is just a regular [BrowserRouter](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/browser-router) you'll need the second method.

Comment: can we use routes without routers in react in second approach ?

Comment: @SpringLearner No, the `Routes` component needs a routing context provided to it in order function.